# django message with redirect not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Why messages framework only work with render with context. But in my case i want redirect because the form validation is failed i want here message to display in frontend ..

```
def user(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        #do action
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Your Message") 
        #return render(request, 'pages/user-account.html') # working fine
        return redirect(reverse('frontend.views.user')) # not working
    return render(request, 'pages/user.html')
```

What am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is not right in your code. !

```
return redirect(reverse('frontend.views.user')) # not working
```

You told that you redirect. But redirecting to where ? `'frontend.views.user'` will get you to the same page but again with different request object. Make your view redirect to another function or use the working one `render` with `request`.